# Parsing string json in javascript throws Unexpected token

Tags: javascript, json

```
var filter1 = " { where:{ businessName:{ $like:'%A'} ,'userId': { $gt: 0} }, limit: 1 }"
```

I want to make pass it like this `JSON`

```
  var filter =  { where:{ businessName:{ $like:'%A'} ,'userId': { $gt: 0} }, limit: 1 }
```

I did this to make it like JSON example.

```
JSON.parse(filter)
```

But it throws the following exception:

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token w in JSON at position 3

Comment: Well your string is no JSON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `JSON` is not valid. Use `""` with all keys and for values, except `numbers` and `bools`

```
var filter1 = '{ "where": { "businessName" :{ "$like":"%A"} ,"userId": { "$gt": 0} }, "limit": 1 }'
```

```js
var filter1 = '{ "where": { "businessName" :{ "$like":"%A"} ,"userId": { "$gt": 0} }, "limit": 1 }';

var filter = JSON.parse(filter1);

console.log(filter);
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not valid JSON string. It's more a JavaScript object literal wrapped in quotes.

In JSON standard all keys should be wrapped in quotes, so here is how your JSON would look like:

```
"{"where":{"businessName":{"$like":"%A"},"userId":{"$gt":0}},"limit":1}"
```

Since your string is simply a JavaScript object wrapped in quotes, you can arrive at the correct JSON string by simply removing quotes:

```
var filter1 = { where:{ businessName:{ $like:'%A'} ,'userId': { $gt: 0} }, limit: 1 }
```

and running it through `JSON.stringify`:

```
JSON.stringify(filter1);
```

Comment: my query engine was unable to recognize it using stringfy

Comment: @danielad, sorry, didn't understand your comment

Comment: yeah , i have to use that json as piece of where query and using stringfy the where query is not recognized.

Comment: @danielad, if you have correct JSON string `"{"where":{"businessName":{"$like":"%A"},"userId":{"$gt":0}},"limit":1}"` and you want to have an object, then you'd have to use `JSON.parse`. If you have simple JavaScript object and you want to have it in JSON, use `JSON.stringify`